# JavaScript : Button disable working only on last row of table

Tags: javascript

I have a search inside an html table, which sets the button to disable if a card number is present in the table. Meaning that if a user inputs "123" in the text box and its present in the table, the submit button is disabled. I have noticed although the *window.alert* is being displayed with every match row, the button is only disabled if the card number is in the last row of the table. I have meddled with the parameter after *(indexOf(filter)* but this causes multiple alerts.

> Function

```
<script>    

            function myFunction() {
              // Declare variables 
              var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
              input = document.getElementById("cardNo");
              filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
              table = document.getElementById("table");
              tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

              // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
                if(input.value.length == 4){
                  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                        if (td) 
                            {
                            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                                tr[i].style.display = "";
                                window.alert("Card Already in Use");
                                $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
                                } else {
                                tr[i].style.display = "none";
                                $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
                                }
                            } 
                        }
                }
            }

        </script>
```

Comment: Imagine your table has 10 rows, row 8 is what is meant to be disabled, and it happens but when you reach row 9, you enable the button again. That's why it only works when it's at the last row. What if you don't try to `$('#submit').prop('disabled', false);`?

Comment: Because if the user then erases the card no and changes it to one that is not in use, he should be allowed to sign in

Comment: After deleting the line I mentioned, how about when the user erases a card, you enable the button and start checking the whole table from the beginning again.

Comment: It will have multiple users, thus multiple cards, I need the button to be disabled only when the textbox has a value that matches a value in the table

Answer (score 0):

I was using a function like yours and I was suffering with the same problem. So, I tried to solve that creating a counter. Therefore, I'm not using alert. Try to do that:

```
    function myFunction() {
      // Declare variables 
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
      input = document.getElementById("cardNo");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("table");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");



      // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
        if(input.value.length == 4){
          //COUNTER
          var count = 0;
          for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            //if (td) { // I don't think so you need to use this if. I didn't use on my function
                    if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                        //window.alert("Card Already in Use"); //commented to avoid to show it all the time
                        $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
                        count = 1;
                    } else {
                        tr[i].style.display = "none";
                        if (count == 0) { // to make on the button
                            $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
                        }
                    }
              //} //commented
           }
        }
    }
```

As I said, I inserted these codes on my function and it worked nice. I didn't try your function, I just adapted your function with my informations. I hope I've helped.